# Custom Property Management with Spring 4.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-properties

Reading [this](https://gist.github.com/rponte/3989915) and [that](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/) I could easily customize my [environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) in a web-app.

My customization is pretty simple, I have some property files packaged in my deployable war file and I would like to have a local properties file on my web-server machine that will override those properties in case of overlap. To do that I implemented the ApplicationContextInitializer interface, loaded my local properties file and used the addFirst method of my [environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html). This made sure my local file overrides the properties files packed in my war.

This worked perfectly. Now I would like to do the same in a java-spring process (not a web-app), How can I do that?

The best solution I have found so far is to add a method to my [configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) class and annotate it with the [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation. This method does exactly what the initialize method of ApplicationContextInitializer.

This solution doesn't serve my needs since I have some beans that are [loaded conditionally](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/) and this (the [conditional annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) code) happens before my @postConstruct method (which is not good since the conditional loading is based upon my properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got over it by loading multiple property-sources:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.company.project")
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = "classpath:/my-jar-properties-file.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = false),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:/path/to/file/local.filesystem.properties.file.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = false) })
public class MyConfiguration { ... }
```

This way the last properties file will override the previous ones, so simple..

Answer (score 0):

For properties management you may use [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html), which enables you to load property files in appropriate order with overrides.
In XML form your config will look like this:

```
<bean id="propertiesConfigurer" 
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jar.file.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:overrides.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Property "ignoreResourceNotFound" will defend application from startup exceptions when "overrides.properies" is missing.

Comment: First I do not use propertiesConfigurer to manage my properties, I use spring Environment. Second, the overriding file is not loaded from classpath but from a fixed path in the file system.